# RavenDB 3 Could not open database named: [Database name] is currently being restarted and cannot be accessed

Tags: ravendb

RavenDB 3: Could not open database named: [Database Name] is currently being restarted and cannot be accessed. We already waited 5 seconds.

We continuously are receiving this message when trying to read from our RavenDB 3 server. This is on a Database that we are using as a cache store that we are reading, writing, and deleting from. There are only about 10,000 documents in it. Had any one else experience this issue/message and have a way to mitigate it? We are not getting it from our other databases but, they have very few deletes.

We are running build: Server Build #3800

Here is the error from our admin logs:

```
2015-11-12T14:57:59.6566457Z;ERROR;null;Raven.Database.Server.WebApi.RequestManager;Could not finalize request properlySystem.InvalidOperationException: Database 'DashboardCache' is currently being restarted and cannot be accessed. We already waited 5 seconds.
   at Raven.Database.Server.Tenancy.DatabasesLandlord.TryGetOrCreateResourceStore(String tenantId, Task`1& database) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Database\Server\Tenancy\DatabaseLandlord.cs:line 136
   at Raven.Database.Server.Tenancy.DatabasesLandlord.<GetDatabaseInternal>d__2.MoveNext() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Database\Server\Tenancy\DatabaseLandlord.cs:line 128
```

It looks like this is what is causing our Database to shutdown:

```
2015-11-12T18:03:18.3754934Z;INFO;<system>;Raven.Database.Indexing.IndexStorage;Resetting index 'Raven/DocumentsByExpirationDate (11)'. Last stored etag: 01000000-0000-8AB7-0000-000000000012. Last commit etag: 01000000-0000-8AB7-0000-000000000011.
```

Any ideas on what might be causing our indexes to be reset so much?

What is comes down to is Raven is cycling this database on and off (reloading it) in about 20 second intervals. We have 10 other databases on this server and they are not doing this. We can not figure out what is triggering the recycle.

Comment: Check the logs, it should explain why this is happening

Comment: Looking at our index errors we do see a number of these types of errors: Could not properly write to index CacheItemOfSqlResult/Sql

Comment: Looking at our server Application Logs, I see events from ESSENT that the database engine is starting a new instance, attaching a database, stopping it, and then looping through the steps again, all in less than 30 seconds.